# "Message Clipped" warning has disappeared from Gmail

Tags: gmail

***Update***: This feature was restored on or before 15 October 2012.

Gmail has a feature that "clips" long messages rather than displaying the whole message body. Googling around, I can [find screenshots](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=gmail+message+clipped+view+entire+message&tbm=isch) of the warning I used to see:

[image: Message clipped View entire message]

> [Message clipped] View entire message

This message contained a link which would display the full message body.

This week, I've noticed long emails (over 100K) are being clipped, with no option to view the entire message body. I've verified this behavior in Google Apps and regular Gmail. The messages are definitely intact on the backend, and they can be viewed in their entirety in Thunderbird.

Does anyone know when and why this feature was removed? Is it coming back any time soon?

Comment: Are they clipped by Gmail or maybe by a mail client used by the person you are mailing with.

Comment: These are multipart messages sent by the PHP mail() command, and I can verify that they're definitely clipped by Gmail's web interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, I'm seeing the same issue. The HTML is all there if you "show original". It appears to be a display issue. I'm told Google is working on a bug fix.
Temporarily, I'm just copying the html and sticking it in http://htmledit.squarefree.com so I can read it.

Comment: They just need to get rid of that feature entirely. It adds essentially no value, is extremely detrimental to a large portion of the user base, and results in bugs (and associated maintenance) such as this.